# How does the Like predicate work in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a field called OrderNumber and there's already a record with that field value of "JY8023".

I tried querying using this SQL code, but it returned nothing.

```
SELECT .... WHERE OrderNumber LIKE "JY8023"
```

I also tried using wildcards and it worked

```
SELECT .... WHERE OrderNumber Like "%JY8023%"
```

So does that mean ***OrderNumber Like "JY9023"*** is not the same as ***OrderNumber = "JY8023"***?

Comment: They are not _always_ the same. I found this page very helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6741b/2). Can you reproduce there?

Comment: I tried this on DB2 on the as/400 and replacing FLD='X' with FLD LIKE 'X' returns the same record.

Comment: @tkendrick20 Please don't reference w3schools. There are more valuable resources like the platform documentation. See [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I wouldn't have referenced it if I didn't think it was a valuable resource to help answer this specific question. It helped me. I'm trying to help others.

Comment: @tkendrick20 My only concern is that users will think that that website is an official resource. I would strongly encourage using platform specific documentation such as [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000751.htm).

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I appreciate the concern (as I'm sure the SO community does as well). I will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you.

Comment: How may characters can OrderNumber hold? Is it greater than 6? Is it a fixed length string (eg. CHAR(10)) or is it a Varchar?

Comment: `"JY8023"` is a column name, not a string literal. `'JY8023'` would be a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the string has characters before or after it, that you can't see. try something like `select length(OrderNumber) WHERE OrderNumber Like "%JY8023%"` to confirm this. Some characters are not only invisible, but unselectable with a cursor. But, they're there and they affect string comparisons.

additional debugging steps to follow will be to use substring to extract the offending part, and other string functions to further inspect the value. like, maybe selecting the string as a hex encoded string will help you identify the bytes.

Comment: Yes, I've looked into the record itself. There were characters before it and apparently it's not showing up when I'm querying. Thank you. It's working now.