# DB2 - Check for a specific character in an IF statement

Tags: triggers, db2

Working on an Insert trigger. How can I check a field for a specific character (in this case, a dash between two airline codes) when creating an If statement within that trigger?

```
IF schema.table.field (**contains**?) '-' THEN
 SET @origin = (SELECT SUBSTR(field,1,3) FROM table WHERE parameters
 SET @delivery = (SELECT SUBSTR(field,5,3)
ELSE
END IF;
```

Comment: Check out the `LIKE` predicate, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834894/how-does-the-like-predicate-work-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

This is what I implemented. So far it seems to be working as intended.

```
IF LOCATE('-',(SELECT table.field FROM table
WHERE table.field2=triggeringtable.field3)) > 0 THEN
SET @dashcheck = 1;
END IF;
```

I'll adjust this if anything breaks. If anyone sees any flaws in this that I may have missed, please feel free to say so.